# Why are my Javascript-dependent feature specs passing when not in Javascript mode?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara, capybara-webkit

I have non-Javascript specs and Javascript feature specs that use capybara/capybara-webkit.

I have some tests that I expected to fail when in non-Javascript mode, but they are passing. I've tried the functionality in my browser with Javascript turned off, and the functionality does indeed not work as expected. But in Capybara, it works.

I've also tried adding `js: false` to the individual test, to make sure there wasn't something hidden in my config turning it on. The spec still passes.

The selenium gem is not included in my Gemfile.

Comment: The way to phrase it is that capybara with the Rack::Test driver (the default) does not run Javascript, while capybara with the webkit driver does run Javascript. That said, I don't know why your tests aren't failing. See if you can think of what in your code or configuration you can add to your question to allow others to help.

Comment: Show us your `features/support/env.rb`. As I read your question now, you always use capybara-webkit, and it will just execute javascript perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2):

I see two possibilities: your tests are correct but there might be some reason why they pass unexpectedly, or your tests are incorrect and are passing for the wrong reason when you run them in Javascript.

A few suggestions for how to debug that apply to both possibilities:

- Use a debugger. (If you have, let us know what you learned.)
- Look at the Rails log from a single run of a spec to see what controller actions are called and in what order.
- Use `save_and_open_page` to snapshot your page and see whether your spec should pass on what you're looking at.

Double-check your tests when run with Javascript:

- Run them with [the poltergeist driver](https://github.com/teampoltergeist/poltergeist) instead of the capybara-webkit driver. It gives better error messages than capybara-webkit and [can be configured](https://github.com/teampoltergeist/poltergeist#customization) to report Javascript error messages.
- Use `save_screenshot` to take an actual screenshot of the page and verify that the spec is not passing for a spurious reason, perhaps because some content is off the screen.

If you want to be sure whether rspec is running Javascript, use `ps` to see whether there is a capybara-webkit or phantomjs process running.

Comment: thanks. this might help. however i'm stuck in the process of swiching to poltergeist, maybe you can help there too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24004130/